# Boost Intersection not working

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

i have a big problem with boost intersection. i would like to intersect a triangle with a quad, but i get a clip:

[image: i46.tinypic.com/2nvuo01.png]

Can somebody help me?

I tried to changed the orientation of the geometry, nothing happened. the intersection work with other triangles, but not with this.

```
typedef model::polygon<model::d2::point_xy<double> > polygon
std::deque<polygon> tmp;
bool ok = intersection(quad, triangle, tmp)
```

The triangle:

```
-213.57   -2.13163e-14   0 
-350      37.5           0 
-350      -2.84217e-14   0
```

The box:

```
BoundingBox(-300, -165, 2, 170, -0.1, 0.1)
```

**UPDATE:**

Here my code. I use gcc 4.7.2 with boost 1.53.0 on Ubuntu 12.10

```
#include <deque>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/wkt/wkt.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/extensions/io/svg/svg_mapper.hpp>

using namespace boost::geometry;

int main()
{
    typedef model::polygon<model::d2::point_xy<double> > polygon;
    typedef typename model::d2::point_xy<double> point_type;

    polygon quad, triangle;

    read_wkt("POLYGON((-213.57 -2.131 , -350.0 37.5 , -350.0 -2.842 , -213.57 -2.131))", triangle);
    read_wkt("POLYGON((-300.0 2 , -300 170 , -165 170 , -165 2 , -300 2))", quad);

    std::deque<polygon> output;
    intersection(quad, triangle, output);

    std::string filename = "intersectiontest.svg";
    std::ofstream svg(filename.c_str());
    svg_mapper<point_type> mapper(svg, 600, 600);

    mapper.add(output[0]);
    mapper.map(output[0], "fill-opacity:0.5;fill:rgb(153,204,0);stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:5");

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My best guess is that this has to do with specifying the points in counterclockwise order when by default `polygon` expects the points to be in clockwise order. So you would need to change it as follows:

```
read_wkt("POLYGON((-213.57 -2.131 , -350.0 -2.842 , -350.0 37.5 , -213.57 -2.131))", triangle);
```

You can read more about this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292202/boostgeometry-intersection-not-working-as-expected)